# Keras stops learning at one point

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

There are about 300 real images of each class. Categorical model with 3 classes.
I've made a model using 2000 generated samples and 10 epochs. The model was ok, but had many false negative predictions.
Than I wanted to improve the model and increased the number of generated samples (real image number not changed) to 20000. In 6th epoch the accuracy began to drop and reached finally 0.2

```
339/666 [==============>...............] - ETA: 52s - loss: 0.2762 - acc: 0.9012
340/666 [==============>...............] - ETA: 52s - loss: 0.2757 - acc: 0.9014
341/666 [==============>...............] - ETA: 52s - loss: 0.2754 - acc: 0.9015
342/666 [==============>...............] - ETA: 52s - loss: nan - acc: 0.9014   
343/666 [==============>...............] - ETA: 52s - loss: nan - acc: 0.8995
344/666 [==============>...............] - ETA: 52s - loss: nan - acc: 0.8976
345/666 [==============>...............] - ETA: 51s - loss: nan - acc: 0.8955
```

Was it overfitting?
Can I prevent it somehow in real time, without restarting the learning? E.g. is it possible, to save the model after each epoch and in such case to take the best model.
Or at least, can Keras break the teaching?

Comment: It is not overfitting. I think there is an option to select best iteration using `from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint`.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar callbacks and in particular ModelCheckpoint were what I was looking for. Looks like I kan control the learning process very well. It was not mentioned in the online course, I used fo knew Keras. Many thanks.
P.S.: If you'll write it as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is certainly  not overfitting here. 
After particular number of iterations your model stops learning(The accuracy curve gets flatter).

To overcome this you can do following

- add more data
- tune hyper parameters

The `keras` library provides a checkpointing capability by a callback API. The `ModelCheckpoint` callback class allows you to define where to checkpoint the model weights, how the file should named and under what circumstances to make a checkpoint of the model.

Using this you can select the best model from number of iterations.

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

"""
    Your Code
"""
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

Refer [How to Check-Point Deep Learning Models in Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/check-point-deep-learning-models-keras/)

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues, and that your loss suddenly becomes `nan` is a bit suspect.

It may stop learning due to your objective function not updating, i.e. not a number.

I would suggest:

- review model loss function
- review featurisation process
- insure inputs cannot cause `nan` to occur

The last point might be most relevant, as very large numbers could cause issues in loss calculation or `nan` sneaking into your feature vector.

Using a `callback` to review the process such as `ModelCheckpoint` or the like can help debug.

Comment: Good points, thanks! First have to read about it. Checking input for nan is a good hint.